# Run web extension's service worker on browser open (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a web extension (Chrome) that checks if the external's API changed. This should be happening periodically (e.g. every 10 mins) and in the background. The plan is to have a service worker that would fire these requests, and replace extension's icon when a change in the response was detected. I have a working code that does exactly that, but I am unable to persist the service worker, and make it run on browser load (i.e. moment when the window opens). I managed to use message API, but that requires the user to click the extension button to open it and only then the extension would continuously run in the background.

This is my service worker code:

```
const browser = chrome || browser;

self.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'CHECK_FOR_NEW_RESOURCES') {
        communicationPort = event.ports[0];

        const compareStructures = setInterval(async () => {
            const currentStructure = await getStructure(event.data.baseURL + 'webservice/rest/server.php', event.data.token);
            const {curr, newResources } = findDifferences(event.data.structure.base, currentStructure);
            if(newResources > 0) {
                communicationPort.postMessage({different: true, structure: curr, newResources,
                    time: new Date().toISOString()});
                browser.action.setIcon({ path: { '48': event.data.newResourcesIcon } });

                clearInterval(compareStructures);
            } else {
                communicationPort.postMessage({ different: false, time: new Date().toISOString() });
                browser.action.setIcon({ path: { '48': event.data.noNewResourcesIcon } });
            }
        }, 900000);
    }
});

const getStructure = async (url, token) => {
// Uses fetch() to get the resources
   ...
};

const findDifferences = (newStructure, oldStructure) => {
   ...
};
```

If it is not possible, what are the viable options to achieve my desired design? Could reverting to manifest ver. 2 help?

Hopefully my description makes sense, and I think it is possible, as I have seen extensions send notifications when the browser is opened.

Comment: Use chrome.alarms API, which exists for this purpose.

Comment: Hmm, I have just had a quick peek at the docs, and it seems like it might indeed help, thank you. However, how would an alarm eventlistener be triggered on browser load? Would this work? - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_codelab_alarms/#update-background-script-alarms

Comment: There's another event: chrome.runtime.onStartup.